# Why does coherent enhancement cannot lead to a power improvement better than the square of interaction length?

Tags: coherence, photonics

I'm studying for an advanced course on photonics. The professor gave us a bunch of reference questions for the exam, like the following:

*Why does coherent enhancement cannot lead to a power improvement better than the square of interaction length, regardless of the order of nonlinearity? (Compare a (partially) coherent and an incoherent interaction for the same nonlinearity order)*

I see that coherent light has a constructive interference with particles. But I don't see why it should have a quadratic enhancement and how it is connected to the order of nonlinearity.

An example of this quadratic enhancement is visible in the SHG conversion efficiency
$$
\eta = \dfrac{I_{2\omega}}{I_{\omega}^2} \propto L^2\text{sinc}^2\left(\dfrac{\Delta k L}{2}\right)
$$

I take mathematical argumentation as well as conceptual.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suppose in your formula $I_\omega$ should be squared

Comment: You are right. I actually copied the formula from the lecture notes and apparently he included that extra $I_\omega$ into the omitted coefficient. But that doesn't make much sense..